# Union of pairwise disjoint sets and Markov chain

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

This question is somehow related to Markov-chains:

Consider a countable set S (nonempty).

Let {$X_n: n \in \mathbb N_0$} be a sequence of random variables and $\forall i_0, ..., i_n \in S$.

$\sum_{i_0,...,i_{n-1}\in S} (X_0 = i_0, ..., X_n = i_n) = (X_n = i_n)$,

where $\sum$ denotes the union of pairwise disjoint sets.

Why does this last expression hold? Is there a way to represent this graphically?

Comment: Because the disjoint union $$\bigcup_{(i_0,\ldots,i_{n-1})\in S^n} (X_0 = i_0, \ldots, X_{n-1} = i_{n-1})$$ is $\Omega$ hence, for every subset $A$ of $\Omega$, $$\bigcup_{(i_0,\ldots,i_{n-1})\in S^n}\left[ (X_0 = i_0, \ldots, X_{n-1} = i_{n-1})\cap A\right]=A$$

Comment: Sorry, but how do I know that your first expression is the sample space?

Comment: Sorry but what do you think this union can be? For every $\omega$ in $\Omega$, $\omega$ is in one of these sets, right?